# Excel solver/opensolver find shortest distance between cities

Tags: excel, solver

I have a table with cities and some of the distances between them, and I want to find all the possibles distances from city C1 to any other city using Excel's Solver (or OpenSolver) addin. The constraint is that I can only use max 2 hops (arcs) between each city (node). So for example I cannot use the path C1-C2-C3-C4 to find the distance from C1 to C4 as it have 3 arcs.

This is the table:

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
C1  -   12  20  25    
C2  12  -   8       4
C3  20  8   -       10
C4  25          -   7
C5      4   10  7   -
```

So using brute force, I would have this:

Options from C1 to C2:

a) C1-C2: 12 miles

b) C1-C3-C2: 20+8=28 miles

c) C1-C3-C5-C2: 20+10+4=34 miles but is invalid (3 hops)

So in solver I have to be able to find these two valid options, and then choose the one with the shortest distance (option a).

The same must be made to routes C1->C3, C1->C4 and C1->C5

Any clues on how to make this? I was thinking in using SUMPRODUCT, but this array don't have all values, and I can't figure out how to enumerate all possible paths from C1 to Cn. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have not solved your problem but have shown you how to use sumproduct() with decision cells B5:F9 to control one city to one city.

Hopefully you could edit / expand for your case...

[image: city planner with solver]

I have put 999 for cases that don't exist, as if you put a zero when looking for a minimum the solver takes that as a good option,

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a jumpstart! If I understand correctly, this example gives the "best" combination between a row and a column, and now I should add more constraints to translate it to my case, given that with this result C4 and C5 are isolated and I couldn't reach any of them starting from C1.